# Simple way to remove all slashes at the end of url in java

Tags: java, string

I need to remove all slashed at the end of url,and i don't known how many slashes at the end.

for example

```
http://www.example.com/user//
```

after removing slashe at the end

```
http://www.example.com/user
```

are there any simple ways like regular expression to do that.

Comment: You could just start iterating from the end of the string and remove all the dashes until you come to a non-dash.

Comment: yes, iterating from the end of the string can remove all the slashes.but i want to use a simple way like  regular expression

Comment: @RichardChan - Always show what you've tried in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `String.replaceAll ("\\/$", "");`

The `$` means that it is at the end of the String

As per @WiktorStribiżew to remove multiple slashes

use `String.replaceAll ("/+$", "");`

Comment: FYI: `/` is not a special regex metacharacter, no need escaping it. Also, `replaceFirst` looks more logical since there can be one string end. And to match one or more occurrences, a `+` quantifier can be used.

Comment: Have you ever used regex in Java? Your answer - `replaceAll ("\\/$", "")` and `replaceAll ("\\+/$", "")` -  is wrong.

Comment: Replace first doesn't seem to be correct. What if there are slashes in between the string?

Comment: Why did you edit to make your answer the same as mine?

Comment: this answer works.thank you,@Scary Wombat

Comment: Ok, I deleted my answer, but it is not really fair.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - You should not have deleted your "correct" answer IMO

Comment: @TheLostMind: I posted that answer just to offset this answer with 2 wrong suggestions. I would not have posted an answer it if this answer had not been posted. So, it is OK for me to delete that one. I cast a close vote anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways: using pattern matching (slightly slower):

`s = s.replaceAll("/$", "");` or `url.replaceFirst("/*$", "");`or

```
s = s.replaceAll("/\\z", "");
```

And using an if statement (slightly faster):

```
if (s.endsWith("/")) {
    s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
}
```

or bit ugly:

```
s = s.substring(0, s.length() - (s.endsWith("/") ? 1 : 0));
```

Please note you need to use s = s, because Strings are immutable.